Moving bright spots in a background image animation
I guys, can you help me that how can I do this animation with my ReactJS project?
static capture
I saw it in Homepage and really like it.
I had search for some library and I find react-three/fiber and Three. I think these library can help me do this but I don't know how to use them.
Thank you!

Try tsparticle library.

@SanketSapate Let me ask one more question, do you know how to use an image as a border (like a map of India) to contain and link to the glowing dots inside?

I would do it with vanilla JS and canvas' 2d-context. It involves the using of double for-loop to find connections between points.
